# Paypal integration in coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion, paypal

I am trying to integrate paypal into my website using coldfusion, everything is working fine except the "return to merchants" url :( ..

The date displayed as the button is getting ad the return url :(

Please give me an idea what is happening there :)

Comment: "The date displayed as the button is getting ad th the return url"?  I'm not sure what you mean here.  Please clarify.

Comment: Did you check your code for typos?  :P

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an older post... But I'll add my 2 bits...

I was using a CFLOCATION push to PayPal and a Return URL back...

The Return URL never worked until I encoded the & symbols...

Now works fine.

```
      <cflocation url="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_xclick&item_name=#bt#&business=#set.paypal#&item_number=#cr# Credits&currency_code=CAD&amount=#numberformat(cost, '_.__')#&return=http://#cgi.HTTP_HOST#/paypal.cfm?typeid=#typeid#%26uid=#session.demshinuser_id#%26credits=#cr#%26src=add" addtoken="no">
```

This is the return URL - with the URL Encoded & - which is %26

```
       return=http://#cgi.HTTP_HOST#/paypal.cfm?typeid=#typeid#%26uid=#session.demshinuser_id#%26credits=#cr#%26src=add" addtoken="no">
```

Some other URL Encoded Values here too if needed...

http://www.degraeve.com/reference/urlencoding.php

Answer (score 0):

Have you viewed or used the sample code supplied on the website.
Check out 'https://www.paypal.com/IntegrationCenter/ic_sample-code.html'